# Codeigniter - making page inside folder index

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a folder called `acc` in the controllers. In the `acc` folder I have a controller named `acc`. I'm a bit confused, as at the minute when you vist the site, you have to visit; http://exampl.com/acc/acc. How would I make it so that the user just has to visit http://example.com/acc, but without moving the acc PHP controller outside the acc folder.

Sorry if it seems confusing, not sure how else to word it!

Comment: I think you want to execute this url http://exampl.com/acc/acc when user hits http://exampl.com/acc. If I understand correctly....?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `config/routes.php`:

```
$route['acc'] = 'acc/acc/index';
```

Answer (score 0):

How about adding an index.php file inside http://example.com/acc with the following content:

```
<?php
require_once ('acc/index.php');
?>
```

It might suit your needs.